# Android Programmatically add views within a for loop

Tags: android, for-loop

Hi i have created an array of dates and i'm wanting to add a header view for each of these dates i'm then gonna run another for loop that will add other views underneath each header. at the moment i'm just wanting to add the header views but currently nothing is showing on screen. so my question is How can i programmatically add views within a for loop?

heres my code

```
public void FillData() throws JSONException{    

      ListView list = getListView();
        list.scrollTo(0, 0);
        list.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);

           list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            View header = inflater.inflate( R.layout.homeheader, list, false);




       fixturesView = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.fixturescell,
                 null);


       //Log.v("MyFix", "fixturesArray = " + fixturesArray);
       if(fixturesArray.length() < 1){

             TextView emptytext = (TextView) fixturesView.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
             emptytext.setText("No Upcoming Fixtures Available");

       }else{
        try{   




            for(int t = 0; t < fixturesArray.length(); t++){
               JSONObject matchDateDict = fixturesArray.getJSONObject(t);
               String matchDate = matchDateDict.getString("matchdate");

               if(matchDatesArray.length() != 0){

                   int lm = t - 1;
                   JSONObject lastDateDict = fixturesArray.getJSONObject(lm);
                   String lastMatchDate = lastDateDict.getString("matchdate");

                   Log.v("MyFix", "lastMatchDate " + lastMatchDate);

                   if(matchDate.equals(lastMatchDate)){
                       Log.v("MyFix", "2 are the same");                        
                   } else {
                       Log.v("MyFix", "add new matchdate to array");   
                       matchDatesArray.put(matchDate);


                   }

               } else {
                   Log.v("MyFix", "add new matchdate to array (first time only)");                      
                   matchDatesArray.put(matchDate);    


               }
            }


            Log.v("MyFix", "matchDatesArray = " + matchDatesArray);

        }catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

         DateHeader = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.redcell,
                 null);

         adapter = new MergeAdapter();

        for(int t = 0; t < matchDatesArray.length(); t++){      

          JSONObject mdheaderdict = matchDatesArray.getJSONObject(t);
           String matchheader = mdheaderdict.getString("matchdate");

               TextView matchdayheader = (TextView) DateHeader.findViewById(R.id.redheadertext);
               matchdayheader.setText(matchheader);
               adapter.addView(DateHeader);


        }



     } 

       setListAdapter(adapter);  


}     


}
```

Comment: are you trying to make header in your list before data or by header you mean list items?

Comment: can you be more precise about want you want to do? maybe add some layout code as well...

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you are searching for

http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/

ListView with section headers and auto-loading of next pages (i.e. "Loading..." on the last item)